# Object reference not instance of an object in wsdl/wcf application

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, soap, wsdl

I am developing a .net 4.5 wcf service. This wcf accepts SOAP messages containing an XML with a custom authentication header. This xml is converted to an object, the object definition is generated using the following steps:

1. Add service reference.
2. Reference the wsdl I recieved containing the object definition.
3. A service reference containing references.cs is generated. This file contains the object definition and some overridable functions in which I put my custom code.

This all works fine up until the point that an error is returned. 
Every now and then(no specific time span for example 3 days or 1 week) the web service will return the error "Object reference is not set to an instance of an object". This seems to happen in the System.ServiceModel.dll, I think this dll is responsible for converting the incoming SOAP Message xml content to an object.
The most strange part is when I restart the web service the error goes away and everything works as expected.

I created an SVCLog and this is the result(same as the error returned when sending the message);

```
<E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent">
<System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system">
<EventID>131076</EventID>
<Type>3</Type>
<SubType Name="Error">0</SubType>
<Level>2</Level>
<TimeCreated SystemTime="2017-02-08T15:01:36.6393145Z" />
<Source Name="System.ServiceModel" />
<Correlation ActivityID="{72d279c1-d80d-4fa9-8a82-eb3ad1b69f0d}" />
<Execution ProcessName="w3wp" ProcessID="12672" ThreadID="8" />
<Channel />
<Computer>RD0003FF4C676E</Computer>
</System>
<ApplicationData>
<TraceData>
<DataItem>
<TraceRecord Severity="Error" Channel="Operational" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord">
<TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.TraceHandledException.aspx</TraceIdentifier>
<Description>Handling an exception. Exception details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationFormatter.TypedMessageParts.SetValue(Object value, Int32 index)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationFormatter.TypedMessageParts.SetTypedMessageParts(Object[] values)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message message, Object[] parameters)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.DeserializeInputs(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage41(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage4(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage3(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage2(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage1(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)</Description>
<AppDomain>/LM/W3SVC/1905215994/ROOT-1-131310166559267906</AppDomain>
<Exception>
<ExceptionType>System.NullReferenceException, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType>
<Message>Object reference not set to an instance of an object.</Message>
<StackTrace>
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationFormatter.TypedMessageParts.SetValue(Object value, Int32 index)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationFormatter.TypedMessageParts.SetTypedMessageParts(Object[] values)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message message, Object[] parameters)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.DeserializeInputs(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage41(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage4(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage3(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage2(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage1(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)
</StackTrace>
<ExceptionString>System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationFormatter.TypedMessageParts.SetValue(Object value, Int32 index)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationFormatter.TypedMessageParts.SetTypedMessageParts(Object[] values)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message message, Object[] parameters)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.DeserializeInputs(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage41(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage4(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage3(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage2(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage1(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)</ExceptionString>
</Exception>
</TraceRecord>
</DataItem>
</TraceData>
</ApplicationData>
</E2ETraceEvent>
```

Does anyone have an idea why this error happens, how to solve or how to debug it? The error occurs before any of my own code is hit. The hard part is that it is random so impossible to easily reproduce(until it occurs again), fixed by restarting and not debuggable. When the exception occurs in debugger mode Visual studio opens the source not found page.

[Edit]
maybe good to know; this wcf is hosted in an Azure app service.

Comment: Do not use service references. They are complex at best and can cause problems. Instead, have consumers call the service directly using ChannelFactory<T>.

Comment: @tom Please explain? The consumers call the web service I create directly, I only use the object definition present in the service reference.

Comment: Yes I know. And I am saying that if you want to fix this problem then the best way of doing this would be to not use a service reference. There are other ways to call a service. Google "how to use ChannelFactory to call a service".

Comment: @tomredfern The Service Reference I use is not hosted somewhere, it is a local .wsdl file I import into my code. This means a ChannelFactory is not a possible solution right?